# Use recipient address as sender address replying to a message in Outlook 2019

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2019

My Google Worspace GMAIL account is correctly configured to send and receive emails using two different email addresses (foo@test.com and bar@test.com). In Outlook 2019 I configured the GMAIL account with the wizard, then I added an additional sender address to send email. Everything work fine, but when I receive an email addressed to bar@test.com, if I click on "reply" or "reply to all" Outlook always select the main address as sender, and I have always to remember to manually change it. Other email clients, for instance Mozilla Thunderbird, automatically selects the sender from email recipent. in practice, if I receive an email addressed to foo@test.com I would like to reply with foo@test.com, if I receive it addressed to bar@test.com I would like to reply with bar@test.com, automatically. is there any way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  You need to point to the sending address in the Outlook advanced settings.

Open Control Panel, Mail (Outlook) and then when the window comes up, Email Accounts.  Click on that to open. Select your Account and click on Change.

Then in More Items, go to Outgoing Server and make sure that is the sending server.

You need to do this to prevent Relaying (which spammers use).

Complete Screen Shot below.

[image: Outlook settings for sending account]

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem. foo@test.com is an alias of bar@test.com. in my inbox I receive messages for both addresses. When I reply to a message, I want to use automatically foo@test.com for messages with recipient foo@test.com, bar@test.com for messages with recipient bar@test.com. In Thunderbird I have this behavior.

Comment: I am not sure any other way as trying to use a different sending address just by naming it amounts to relaying.